# Condition when inequality with numbers is true

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

Let $n\geq 1, m>1, k\leq n$.

I am trying to find condition on $m,$ that 
$$
4\sqrt{\pi}(2m)^{mn}\leq2^k
$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$4\sqrt{\pi}(2m)^{mn} = 4\sqrt{\pi}2^{mn}m^{mn} \geq 4\sqrt{\pi}2^k m^{mn}$ since $k \leq n$ and $m > 1$.

Clearly, $4\sqrt{\pi}2^k m^{mn} > 2^k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Are you sure that the conditions on $n,m$ and $k$ are correct ?